# Inconsistency between preview and actual snippet when adding quotes

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, blockquote

I'm trying to add a "quote" snippet to an existing answer. When I view this in Edit it look like this:

[image]

When I click "Save edits" it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I've resolved the issue in the post in question using `##` headings rather than underlining, although still a bug that preview and result are different

Comment: Yeah just to be clear the underline syntax was added by pressing the title button in the editor so if your not familiar with MD it's extra confusing

Comment: Already reported on MSE and already marked [meta-tag:status-review]: [Quoted headings are rendered properly on preview but not when posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351170/289905).

Comment: Ok, looks like someone is looking at this, not sure what to do about this question but it seems to be being tracked on MSE

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of this [post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351170/quoted-headings-are-rendered-properly-on-preview-but-not-when-posted)

Comment: Bugs shouldn't be closed because they were asked on another meta site.