# Bug in heading when using quotes

Tags: bug, design, markdown-rendering

Using heading in quotes has some strange behavior, for instance:

```
>Quote title
>---
>Rest of the quotation
```

The above should make **Quote title** a header, and indeed it does in the preview section, but strangely, when the post is saved, it then turns into an underline:

> Quote title
>
> ---
>
> Rest of the quotation.

When you [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/401940/edit) the post it becomes, again, a header as seen in the preview, and when you save it, it becomes again an underline.

---

Here is a pic of the edit preview:

> [image]

---

This doesn't seem normal to me, I believe I've done this before without issues, this may be related to recent changes in the post formatting.

Comment: It would be more clear if you insert the corresponding markdown code in the post as code, in addition to the obtained display result. I don't see anything when clicking on your link.

Comment: @Damien I changed it, the link is just to edit the post so the behavior can be seen, of course it's the same as clicking in edit. When you say displayed result, do you mean as an image?

Comment: For the displayer result, i was considring what is already displayed in the post at the beginning. Sorry not being clear.

Comment: @Damien I see, anyway I edited in a picture of the issue, let me know if you think it's ok, feel free to edit it if you think an improvement is required.

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but I made several tests with *pandoc*, with strict markdown, pandoc markdown, commonmark: I always get the same expected result, with a title

Comment: @Damien, it helps of course, maybe establishing that this is indeed a bug, I just dug around a litle bit and the expected result can be achieved by using `## Quote title`. Still it seems like something that should be addressed.

Comment: The [reference implementation](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%3ETitle%0A%3E---%0A%3ETexxt%0A) agrees with you.

Comment: @Braiam, it seems so, good share.

Comment: Duplicate of [Inconsistency between preview and actual snippet when adding quotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400831/4642212) and already reported on MSE with tag [tag:status-review]: [Quoted headings are rendered properly on preview but not when posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351170/289905).

Comment: @user4642212, I did look for duplicates before asking, I guess I missed those, well spotted. I'll accept the duplicate.